# Functor associative law confusion

Tags: javascript, haskell, monads, functor, associative

I've been confused by associative law of functor(Endofunctor) for weeks.

I know every endofunctor forms composition/associative feature.

> Composition is associative. Basically that means that when you’re composing multiple functions (morphisms if you’re feeling fancy), you don’t need parenthesis:

```
h∘(g∘f) = (h∘g)∘f = h∘g∘f
```

> Let’s take another look at the composition law in JavaScript:
>
> Given a functor, F:

```
const F = [1, 2, 3];
```

> The following are equivalent:

```
F.map(x => f(g(x)));
// is equivalent to...
F.map(g).map(f);
```

However, as shown the code below, especially the later part:

```
console.log("===================");
const take1 = a => a //any
  .map(g)
  .map(f)
  .map(trace);
```

this will lead an type error:

```
//  const r3 = v.map(take1); //TypeError: a.map is not a function
```

, and surely:

```
const take2 = a => Identity(a) //Identity(any)
  .map(trace)
  .map(g)
  .map(trace)
  .map(f)
  .map(trace);
const r4 = v.map(take2);
```

works.

What I feel wrong with is in the `take2` function, the requirement to transform the type of the argument:`a` to `Identity(a)` is not really composing functions.

I also understand that Monads are to avoid this composition problem, and I wonder if this issue is simply due to lack of "left-right Identiy law of Monads" and the functor associative law is still satisfied, or there may be different layers of associative laws, and in functor, a certain layer of associative law is obviously satisfied, but another layer of associative law is broken as seen the sample above.

Can you clarify?

The sample code is certainly in JavaScript, but I still tag Haskell, since the community is strong on the topic, so please excuse me.

Thank you.

```js
const trace = x => {
  console.log(x);
  return x;
};
const Identity = value => ({
  map: fn => Identity(fn(value)),
  valueOf: () => value,
});
const u = Identity(2);
const f = n => n + 1;
const g = n => n * 2;
// Composition law
const r1 = u
  .map(x => f(g(x)));
const r2 = u
  .map(g)
  .map(f);
r1.map(trace); // 5
r2.map(trace); // 5
console.log("===================");
const take1 = a => a //any
  .map(g)
  .map(f)
  .map(trace);
const v = Identity(100);
//  const r3 = v.map(take1); //TypeError: a.map is not a function
const take2 = a => Identity(a) //Identity(any)
  .map(trace)
  .map(g)
  .map(trace)
  .map(f)
  .map(trace);
const r4 = v.map(take2);
```

PS/EDIT:

Another reason to ask this is if we simply view the function sequence f/g/h as data sequence and cut and paste like strings, the structure becomes:

```
h∘(g∘f) != (h∘g)∘f != h∘g∘f
```

without flatten procedures intentionally. This breaks associative, and if only the flatten process probably by the left/right identity law of Monoids/Monads make things associative, are those identity law and associative are somehow not isolated each other??

Comment: The problem you're asking about really has nothing to do with the associativity law.

Comment: Also a suggestion: to fully get into the functional thinking, better don't use `trace` but only display final values. (Not that Haskellers don't use `trace` for debugging, or rather [`traceShowId`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceShowId), but only as a hack to find out about some value discrepancy detail. First comes always the typechecking stage.)

Answer (score 3):

With `const r3 = v.map(take1)` you already go into one layer of map-yness, you *enter the functor*, if you will. Inside the functor, you have pure, unwrapped values. But `take1` itself tries to use `map` on those values again! That *can* work, but only if the values are themselves functor values – like, a nested `Identity`.

To use a function that already uses `map` internally, simply *apply* it to the functor-value:

```js
const f = n => n + 1;
const g = n => n * 2;

const Identity = value => ({
  map: fn => Identity(fn(value)),
  valueOf: () => value,
});

const take1 = a => a //any
  .map(g)
  .map(f);

const v = Identity(100);
const r3 = take1(v);

console.log(r3.valueOf());
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I know of, and I thought I clarified in the Question. So far unfortunately, you don't answer anything in terms of this topic.

Comment: Well, it's not really clear what your question _is_.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to sort out terminology.

In category theory, a category *C* consists of *objects* and *morphisms* (also called *arrows*). A functor *F* between two categories *C* and *D*, written *F: C -> D*, maps objects of *C* to objects of *D* and morphisms of *C* to morphisms of *D*.

You can compose functors (in the obvious way).

Composition of functors is associative: Given *F : C -> D*, *G : D -> E* and *H : E -> F*, their composition (which is a functor from *C* to *F*) doesn't need parenthesis.

You can also compose morphisms (inside a category). Composition of morphisms is also associative.

Moreover, a functor must respect composition of morphisms (that is, *F(g∘f) = F(g)∘F(f)*). This is completely different from associativity.

An *endofunctor* is a functor from some category to the same category, *F : C -> C*.

In Javascript, there a no types, so to make it into a category, imagine a single object (some universal type) as the only object. Morphisms are the functions with one arguments.

Now this

```
const F = [1, 2, 3];
```

is not a functor: You didn't say how objects get mapped (though there's not much choice), you didn't say how morphisms (Javascript functions) get mapped.

However, you can define a functor *Array* for Javascript like this:

a) Our universal type gets mapped to itself. (If Javascript had types, we would map the type *t* to the type "arrays of *t*").

b) A function *f* gets mapped to a function from an array to an array, by applying it "pointwise". This is *map* on arrays in Javascript: *Array(f) = (x => x.map(f))* (using `=>` for functions).

Note that *Array* isn't anything you can completely write down in Javascript.

Now this functor respects composition of morphisms (Javascript functions) etc. etc., as one can easily work out. And one intermediate step in that would be that indeed *x.map(f).map(g) = x.map(y => g(f(y))* (informally, it doesn't matter if you first apply *f* to all elements of the array *x*, and after that, apply *g* to all of them, or if you immediately apply *g* after *f* to all elements of the array).

It would also be associative if we compose it with other functors (though we don't have examples for other functors in Javascript yet).

Let's leave monads out of the picture for now.

Does that help?

Comment: “In Javascript, the values form a category.” That doesn't make sense, does it? What are the values supposed to be in the category? They certainly aren't objects of the category.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: You are right, I got confused because there are no types. Edited.